# firebase.auth(...).fetchProvidersForEmail is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to call `fetchProvidersForEmail` from my `nodejs` server application. But it gives me error:

> firebase.auth(...).fetchProvidersForEmail is not a function

My simple `nodejs` snippet is:

```
firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail('foo@bar.com').then(function(){
  console.log("OK");
});
```

I also found that this function is there in the node library. ([Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchProvidersForEmail))

What's wrong here?

Comment: did you find the problem?

Comment: @RezaShoja Yes, I've already added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any official documentation for this. But, I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/_6Rhro3zBbk/u8hB1oVRCgAJ) which shows that auth is possible with the latest sdk. [This thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/_6Rhro3zBbk/x-W_dSJWCgAJ) shows how to do that:

```
var clientApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: <API_KEY>,
  authDomain: "<AUTH_DOMAIN_NAME>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseUrl: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
}, 'client');

// ...
var clientAuth = clientApp.auth();   // has methods for end-user authentication and account management
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably initializing the app using a service account. You have to initialize it with an apiKey and not with a serviceAccount. When you initialize with a serviceAccount you can validate id tokens and mint custom tokens. For client functionality like fetchProvidersForEmail, you have to just pass the apiKey without the service account.